# Renesas Electronics USB 3.0 Host Controller Driver replacement software

Tags: windows-7, laptop, usb

My usb 3.0 is not working. I tried to install different drivers but no avail.

[image]

System info
[image]

Comment: upgrade to Windows 8/10, they have a generic inbox usb 3.0 driver

Comment: I got it working. not sure what solved it but after installing a bunch of kb files from HP and rebooting its working now.

Comment: post as answer which KB files you downloaded and installed.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps. I don't know which one made it work but the list below are the one I installed.

https://downloadmirror.intel.com/21129/eng/Intel(R)_USB_3.0_eXtensible_Host_Controller_Driver.zip

https://downloadmirror.intel.com/22824/eng/Intel(R)_USB_3.0_eXtensible_Host_Controller_Driver_4.0.6.60.zip

http://whp-hou9.cold.extweb.hp.com/pub/softpaq/sp54501-55000/sp54511.exe

http://whp-hou9.cold.extweb.hp.com/pub/softpaq/sp58501-59000/sp58725.exe

After installing the KB's I made a full shutdown and Turned on. Now its working.

Answer (score 1):

This did the trick for me:

Website: https://plugable.com/drivers/renesas/

Direct driver download: https://s3.amazonaws.com/plugable/bin/Renesas/2014-03-Plugable-Renesas-USB-3.0-200-2.1.39.0.zip

Comment: Worked for me and My Asus M4AT-V motherboard, been banging my head for hours, thanks. @pkSML

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a tool like [DriversCloud](https://www.driverscloud.com/) to find the right drivers for your device ?

If it doesn't, this tool will also help you to find the precise model of device, because Renesas Electronics has really large series of "USB 3.0 Host Controller". You can then post it here.

Comment: no I haven't tried.